# Getting Data Attributes on Dynamically Created Select Lists using Javascript

Tags: javascript, custom-data-attribute, selectlist

I have a onchange function on my dynamically created select list which is trying to get the data- attributes but I am getting a "undefined" value.

```
function changed_option(barcode,id,priceid,price){
  var barcode=barcode;
  var record=id;
  var change_action = ( $(this).find(':selected').data('change_action'));
  var change_amount = ( $(this).find(':selected').data('change_amount'));
  alert("Change Action: "+change_action);
  alert("Change Amount: "+change_action);
}
```

The HTML generated code is:

```
<select onchange="changed_option('QKCLASS01NB','1282389738','price_QKCLASS01NB','125.00')"class="form-control col-md-10 center" id="1282389738" required="required" name="attributes[Payment Option]">
<option value="">---Select Option---</option><option data-change_action="0"data-change_amount="0.00">Full Price</option>
<option data-change_action="2"data-change_amount="20.00">Down Payment</option>
</select>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

```
function changed_option(barcode,id,priceid,price){
  var barcode=barcode;
  var record=id;
  var change_action = ( $('#'+id).find(':selected').data('change_action'));
  var change_amount = ( $('#'+id).find(':selected').data('change_amount'));
  alert("Change Action: "+change_action);
  alert("Change Amount: "+change_amount);
}
```

Since you are using the onchange event. this will not provide you the reference of your dropdown. You can use the id of ther dropdown to get the seleced value.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `this` to `changed_option` to target the correct element.

```js
function changed_option(el, barcode,id,priceid,price){
  var barcode=barcode;
  var record=id;
  var change_action = ( $(el).find(':selected').data('change_action'));
  var change_amount = ( $(el).find(':selected').data('change_amount'));
  alert("Change Action: "+change_action);
  alert("Change Amount: "+change_amount);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="changed_option(this, 'QKCLASS01NB','1282389738','price_QKCLASS01NB','125.00')"class="form-control col-md-10 center" id="1282389738" required="required" name="attributes[Payment Option]">
<option value="">---Select Option---</option><option data-change_action="0"data-change_amount="0.00">Full Price</option>
<option data-change_action="2"data-change_amount="20.00">Down Payment</option>
</select>
```